# How to enumerate a set of possible values used across services in python?

Tags: python, enums, enumeration

The title isn't exactly clear, I'm having trouble wording the problem correctly, but maybe an example will help.

Let's say that I've implemented a job service in python. This is a server that accepts posted data that contains a job definition and performs the job. The server only has a set of jobs that it can perform, anything else is invalid and requires an error be returned to the caller.

```
JOB_TYPE_1 = "job_type_1"
JOB_TYPE_2 = "job_type_2"
JOB_TYPE_3 = "job_type_3"
VALID_JOB_TYPES = [JOB_TYPE_1, JOB_TYPE_2, JOB_TYPE_3]

def run_job(job_type, payload):
  if job_type not in VALID_JOB_TYPES:
    raise ValueError("invalid job_type value")
  elif job_type == JOB_TYPE_1:
    run_job_type_1(payload)
  elif job_type == JOB_TYPE_2:
    run_job_type_2(payload)
  elif job_type == JOB_TYPE_3:
    run_job_type_3(payload)

@get("/api/job", method=['POST'])
def accept_post():
    payload = request.json
    job_type = request.vars.get('job_type')
    run_job(job_type, payload)
```

The caller can then do something like

```
payload = dict(some_key="some_value")
requests.post("https://localhost/api/job?job_type=job_type_1", json=payload)
```

So this works. Namely, it

1. assigns meaningful strings to the job names, this way the caller doesn't have to have access to the source code enumerations
2. has the job names held by variables so we don't have magic strings laying around the source code (at least the job-processing source code)
3. checks that the job type is valid `job_type in VALID_JOB_TYPES`).

The issue is that.. this seems wrong. It seems like there should be some enumeration-like structure that can handle most of this logic.

I know that python has enumerations, and I could do something like this

```
def JobType(Enum):
  JOB_TYPE_1=1
  JOB_TYPE_2=2
  JOB_TYPE_3=3
```

The issue is that, then

1. I don't have a way to see if an incoming `job_type` value is a valid `JobType` enum, there is no `if job_type in JobTypes` operator.
2. The caller of my service doesn't have access to this enumeration, so they're stuck either redefining it themselves or sending over magic numbers (i.e. `1` for `JOB_TYPE_1`, etc.) to specifiy which jobs they want to run.

So, ideally, I'd have a way of defining an enum that maps to meaningful strings and allows me to do a comparison of any random string against the enumeration to ensure that it is itself a valid job type.

Comment: Why you cannot use `dict` (or `OrderedDict`) to holding information about a jobs? Or may be a `dict` with job_type strings as keys and handler functions as values?

Comment: I guess I didn't do that because I still end up using strings around the handler code. So `if job_type == "job_type_1": job_map[job_type].run()`. I wanted to use meaningful variables to hold the job names

Comment: Something like `if job_type not in job_map: raise ValueError() else: job_map[job_type].run()`. No multiple `elif` requried. For more code consistency you can use custom decorator to add handlers to `job_map`.